# Core image filter with custom metal kernel doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, metal, core-image, cikernel

I've made a custom `CIFilter` based on a custom kernel, I can't make it work the output image is filled with black and I can't understand why.
Here is the shader:

```
// MARK: Custom kernels
    float4 eight_bit(sampler image, sampler palette_image, float paletteSize) {
        float4 color = image.sample(image.coord());
        float dist = distance(color, palette_image.sample(float2(0,0)));
        float4 returnColor = palette_image.sample(float2(0,0));
        for (int i = 1; i < floor(paletteSize); ++i) {
            float tempDist = distance(color, palette_image.sample(float2(i,0)));
            if (tempDist < dist) {
                dist = tempDist;
                returnColor = palette_image.sample(float2(i,0));
            }
        }
        return returnColor;
    }
```

The first sampler is the image that needs to be elaborated the second image is and image that contains the colors of a specific palette that must be used in that image.
The palette image is create from an array of `RGBA` values, passed to a `Data` buffer an created by using this CIImage initializer `init(bitmapData data: Data, bytesPerRow: Int, size: CGSize, format: CIFormat, colorSpace: CGColorSpace?)`. The image is 1px in height and number of color wide. The image is obtained correctly and it looks like that:
[image: Image from palette]
Trying to inspect the shader I've found:

- If I return `color` I get the original image, thus means that the sampler `image` is passed correctly
- If I try to return a color from any pixel in `palette_image` the resulting image from the filter is black

I'm starting to think that the `palette_image` is somehow not passed correctly. Here how the image is passed through the filter:

```
 override var outputImage: CIImage? {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else
        {
            return nil
        }
        let palette = EightBitColorFilter.palettes[Int(0)]
        let paletteImage = EightBitColorFilter.image(from: palette)
        let extent = inputImage.extent
        let pixellateImage = inputImage.applyingFilter("CIPixellate", parameters: [kCIInputScaleKey: inputScale])
//        let sampler = CISampler(image: paletteImage)
        let arguments = [pixellateImage, paletteImage, Float(palette.count)] as [Any]

        let final = kernel.apply(extent: extent, roiCallback: {
                (index, rect) in
                return rect
        }, arguments: arguments)

        return final
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sampling coordinates are off.

Samplers use relative coordinates in Core Image, i.e. `(0,0)` corresponds to the upper left corner, `(1,1)` the lower right corner of the *whole* input image.

So try something like this:

```
float4 eight_bit(sampler image, sampler palette_image, float paletteSize) {
    float4 color = image.sample(image.coord());
    // initial offset to land in the middle of the first pixel
    float2 firstPaletteCoord = float2(1.0 / (2.0 * palletSize), 0.5);
    float dist = distance(color, palette_image.sample(firstPaletteCoord));
    float4 returnColor = palette_image.sample(firstPaletteCoord);
    for (int i = 1; i < floor(paletteSize); ++i) {
        // step one pixel further
        float2 paletteCoord = firstPaletteCoord + float2(1.0 / paletteSize, 0.0);
        float4 paletteColor = palette_image.sample(paletteCoord);
        float tempDist = distance(color, paletteColor);
        if (tempDist < dist) {
            dist = tempDist;
            returnColor = paletteColor;
        }
    }
    return returnColor;
}
```

Comment: I understand that you are the master of Core Image and Apple should probably hire you, their documentation about CI is so confusing. It works, thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help :)